# grouping rows data in tableau and get the result

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table in tableau

```
store  year   project  store_amount
1      2012   p1       1200
1      2012   p2       1200
1      2012   p3       1200
2      2019   p4       1700
2      2019   p5       1700
3      2012   p6       2900
```

What I want in tableau is total store amount by store id, so it should show 1200 for store 1, 1700 for store 2, 2900 for store 3

And when I want to see the total store amount I want the sum of store 1,2,3 , 1200+1700+2900

Another grouping I want to do is by year: So for 2012 it should be (1200+2900)

I tried a lot of ways but can't do it.

Comment: If you want to group by a field in Tableau (in the same sense as the SQL keywords GROUP BY), then you tell Tableau that by converting the field to a dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of options, it basically depends on the specifics of what you're trying to do. Based on you wanting so sum the total across all stores and also group by year try the following calculated field formula:

{ FIXED [Store]:MIN([Store Amount])}

Sum this new field - in other words it's the sum of the minimum (or max or average - based on your data it doesn't matter) values